# Mock getResourceAsStream( ) method

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a method call like this

```
class classname
    {
    void somemethod()
    {
    InpuStream someImputStream=classname.class.getResourceAsStream("some string");
    }
    }
```

Is there any way to mock the method call?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can first introduce a method for returning the input stream

```
 class classname
        {
        void somemethod()
        {
           InpuStream someImputStream = getInputStream();
        }

        protected InputStream getInputStream() {
            return classname.class.getResourceAsStream("some string");
        }


        }
```

In your test case

```
classname testObject = org.mockito.Mockito.spy(new classname());
org.mockito.Mockito.when(testObject.getInputStream()).thenReturn(...);
```